# js regex - checking number with optionally ending with /

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to check if the url is either in the pattern that:

end with digits:

```
www.example.com/projects/123
```

or possibly end with digits and `/`:

```
www.example.com/projects/123/
```

which I don't know if user is going to add in the `/` at the end of the url.

What I have currently is:

```
var lastPart = window.location.pathname.substr(window.location.pathname.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

lastPart.match(/\d$/);
```

this will return `true` if it end with digits. if I do:

```
lastPart.match(/\d\/$/);
```

this will return `true` if it end with digits with `/` at the end. However, we cannot be sure if the user will put in the `/` or not.

So, How can we write the `regex` which end with digits and optionally `/` at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a `?` quantifier after `/`:

```
/\d+\/?$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WqsQha/1).

**Details**

- `\d+` -  1+ digits
- `\/?`  - 1 or 0 occurrences of `/`
- `$` - end of string.

JS demo:

```js
var strs = ['www.example.com/projects/123', 'www.example.com/projects/123/', 'www.example.com/projects/abc'];
var rx = /\d+\/?$/;
for (var s of strs) {
  console.log(s, '=>', rx.test(s));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this and make the `/` optional `?`:

[`\d+\/?$`](https://regex101.com/r/vxnO0d/1)

**Explanation**

- Match one or more digits `\d+`
- Match an optional forward slash `\/?`
- Assert the end of the string `$`

```js
var strings = [
    "www.example.com/projects/123",
    "www.example.com/projects/123/"
];

for (var i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    console.log(/\d+\/?$/.test(strings[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
/\d+(\/?)$/
```

Explanation

- `\d+` will match one or more digits
- `(\/?)` will match zero or one `/`
- `$` asserts end of string

For example

```
window.location.pathname.match( /\d+(\/?)$/ )
```

**Demo**

```js
var regex = /\d+(\/?)$/;

var str1 = "www.example.com/projects/123";
var str2 = "www.example.com/projects/123/";
var badStr ="www.example.com/projects/as";

console.log( !!str1.match( regex ) );
console.log( !!str2.match( regex ) );
console.log( !!badStr.match( regex ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var string = 'www.example.com/projects/123/';
console.log(string.match(/\d+(\/?)$/));
var string = 'www.example.com/projects/123';
console.log(string.match(/\d+(\/?)$/));
```